# how to add button in gridview dynamically

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamically-generated

i am creating `gridview` dynamically... Now i want to add some buttons in that and also add their relative rowCommand Events. please help me to do this. this is how I create GridView's dynamically in my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtEmployees.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();


                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.ID = "gv" + dtTasks.Rows[i]["TaskID"].ToString() + dtEmployees.Rows[i]["EmpID"].ToString();

                DataTable dt = dtTasks.Clone();

                foreach (DataRow dr in dtTasks.Rows)
                {
                    if (dr["EmpID"].ToString() == dtEmployees.Rows[i]["EmpID"].ToString())
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                    }
                }
                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataBind();
                tc.Controls.Add(gv);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                tblMain.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Though i don't test it but logically it would be like below:

```
if(e.Row.RowIndex > -1) 
{ 
    Button button = new Button();
    button.CommandArgument = dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex][i].ToString(); 
    button.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "button_Clicked");

    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(button);
}
```

Where e would be `GridViewRowEventArgs` .And those code would be placed in your `for/foreach` loop.Probably like..

```
for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Then make an **button event handler**:

```
protected void button_Clicked(object sender, EventAgrs e)
{
   if (sender is Button)
   {
     try
     {
        String value = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
     }
     catch
     {
       //Check for exception
     }
   }
}
```

Also can view..

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1234622.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know you did it because you asked before a few months, but I just answered for the others who research about this point.

just do this at the function to displayed:

```
        DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
        col.Text = "ADD";
        col.Name = "MyButton";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```