# Android: How to add buttons to GridView dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-gridview

I am trying to add buttons to a GridView for each string from textArray.

```
void addButtons() {

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setText(textArray[i]);
        newButton.setId(i);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        buttons.add(newButton);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Button> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Button>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, buttons);
    gridView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

But in result, I get this: [Virtual Device screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akEE2.png)

What can be wrong? Or maybe there is a better way to do the same thing? I've tried LinearLayout and everything was ok, but I was not able to scroll down.

[how to add button in gridview dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588934/how-to-add-button-in-gridview-dynamically) might have a solution, but, to be honest, it is too hard for me at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add button in gridview dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588934/how-to-add-button-in-gridview-dynamically)

Comment: Sorry, this tread might have a solution, but, to be honest, it is too hard for me at the moment to understand what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it shows how to create buttons during runtime https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49225/dynamic-buttons-in-gridview

Answer (score 0):

*So the initial problem was to get a view with programmatically generated buttons. The first solution was a LinearLayout, but I found out that I was not able to scroll it down, so the number of buttons was limited. On the internet, I found that GridView also can do such a task and it would be scrollable. Well, it is true, but I have stuck upon the problem mentioned in this thread.*

After a few days of googling I found that LinearLayout inside ScrollView is what I need. So here is both my xml and java code for someone who stumbles up on the same problem:

```
    <ScrollView
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cityLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- Content here -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

```
void addButtons() {

    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.cityLayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < cityArray.length; i++) {
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setText(cityArray[i]);
        newButton.setId(i);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        linearLayout.addView(newButton, layoutParams);
    }
}
```

Anyway, thanks to everyone for help!